# Mount options for a deep-learning workstation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, mount, partition

So, my university advisor assigned me to setup a deep-learning workstation in our laboratory to do some research. But it's my first contact with linux and system administration and I'm feeling a bit lost in some aspects of the installation. One of they is about mount options for each volume.

I'm using LVM to manage the disks (the server have a 480GB SSD and a 6TB HD), it seems that the SSD have plenty of space for all the software and libraries that we gonna use (CUDA, cuDNN, Keras, Tensorflow, etc), but during the LVM configuration of disk partitions, there is some mount options that I can select, like discard, noatime, nodiratime, relatime, usrquota, grpquota, etc.

I already did plenty of research on stack overflow, quora and etc, but I couldn't find any useful information for my case about which options to select.

The idea for the workstation is that everyone from our lab (about 15 students) could use it for processing deep-learning models inside a virtual environment (python).

- Ubuntu Server 16.04
- CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2620 2,10GHz
- 64GB of RAM (DDR4)
- SSD 480GB
- HD 6TB
- GPU: 3x Titan X Ultimate Pascal (2016) 12GB

What I'm asking here is some advice about the mount options for the logical volumes (I only created two - root [360GB] and swap [16GB] - inside the SSD) and some suggestions about system administration of deep-learning workstations, from your experiences with this type of setup.

Comment: IMO, you're going about this backwards.  What are you trying to fix by changing the mount options?  If you don't have a reason, don't do it.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the Mount Options. The Installation will set them up right for you. Just have a look on the Partitioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVM is a good choise for Partitioning your System because you can resize it when you see that the need has changed.
With the SSD you will have a good Data I/O for Database Systems.
But you must be careful not to mix up the SSD with the normal HD, because it will slow the Data I/O Performance down.
So after creating the `Swap` Partition on the SSD you might use the rest of it for the Root Partition to install all Software there.

In a Multi-User System you might want to control the size of the User usable Partition.
So you might set up a separate Partition from the 6TB HD for the `/home` Directory.

With this Setup you might be fine.